# Angular9 Exception: Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-class

Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

I have migrated the angular project from version 8 to 9 and facing this type of errors.

```
 src/app/components/header/header.component.ts:28:16
    28   templateUrl: './header.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
src/app/components/header/header.component.html:72:109 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

72                         <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.username" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': userName.errors && userName.touched}" #userName="ngModel" class="form-control user-icon" name="userName" required minlength="2" maxlength="30"
                                                                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/components/header/header.component.ts:28:16
    28   templateUrl: './header.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
src/app/components/header/header.component.html:83:79 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
```

Even I have imported the CommonModule and FormsModule and added them to the imports array in app.module.ts.
I have declared all components in app.module.ts

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Remember you need import the modules in the module where you are declared the component. Think in a module as some independent that you can copy to another app, so you need indicate to Angular all the necessary "libraries"

Comment: Could you share the code of the module where you declare `HeaderComponent`?